# GridView of Colored Squares -- Android

Tags: android, gridview, adapter, android-relativelayout

I want to make a GridView that contains randomly colored squares, and I want to put that into a RelativeLayout so that buttons above and below the grid can alter the state of the grid (i.e the colors of certain squares). I'm having trouble figuring out how to create these colored squares and put them into the grid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gameLayout"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/colorGrid"
    android:layout_width="200dip" 
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:columnWidth="90dip"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="0.0dip"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0.0dip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/redButton"
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
    android:text="RED"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_below="@id/colorGrid" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/yellowButton"
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
    android:text="YELLOW"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/redButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/greenButton"
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
    android:text="GREEN"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/redButton" 
    android:layout_below="@id/colorGrid" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/lightBlueButton"
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
    android:text="LIGHT BLUE"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/redButton" 
    android:layout_below="@id/colorGrid" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/darkBlueButton"
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
    android:text="DARK BLUE"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/redButton" 
    android:layout_below="@id/redButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/purpleButton"
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
    android:text="PURPLE"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/redButton" 
    android:layout_below="@id/redButton" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the squares to be right next to each other that's why I reduced the vertical and horizontal spacing in the grid to 0 each.

Should I create these squares programmatically and use an Adapter of some sort to add them to the grid? I just need help getting started. Thank you!

My adapter class code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GameAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context mContext;

public GameAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {

    return 10;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    if(convertView==null){
        view=new View(mContext);
    }else{
        view = (View) convertView;
    }
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb((int)(Math.random()*255), (int)(Math.random()*255), (int)(Math.random()*255)));
    return view;
}
```

}

The call in my activity class:

```
setContentView(R.layout.gamelayout);
GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.colorGrid);
gridView.setAdapter(new GameAdapter(TheActivity.this));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gridview already returns a grid of squares. So you can change the color of each square from the adapter.

```
public int getCount() {

    return 10;
}

private int r,g,b;
r=Rand with bounds [0,255]
g=...
b=....

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


   View view;
    view=new ImageView(mContext);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));

return view;
```

Comment: Okay great! I just tried that now and it makes perfect sense. I can't get the colors to show, however. I might not be implementing the adapter correctly; this is my first time using an adapter. I'm adding my java code now so you can take a look.

Comment: that way you implementing the adapter you cannot have a background color since the imageview is ..well an image that has it's own color on top of the background color. The imageviews are there to display images of just plain colors? Answer to this so i can write some code

Comment: It won't let me since I'm a relatively new user to stackoverflow :( lol

Comment: i didn't mean accept my answer . I mean answer me so i know what u want. anyway i'll update the code new maybe it fits

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I just want the grid to fill the squares with a plain color and have the ability to change that color later (which i can figure out later). I've tried the updated code and still no luck, it remained all black. I thought maybe making the RelativeLayout have a transparent background would help but that did nothing as well.

Comment: did you change the getCount from 0 to 10?

Comment: Yep. When I saw that you did that I thought that would be the problem but it didn't change anything (that i can see at least).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but change weakwire's adapter getView too:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
        if (convertView == null) {   
            convertView = new ImageView(context);
            convertView.setMinimumHeight(32);
            convertView.setMinimumWidth(32);

        }
        ((ImageView)convertView).setImageDrawable(new ColorDrawable((int) getItem(position)));
        return convertView;     
    }
```